# index() apenas para elementos com uma classe especifica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso utilizar o `index()` apenas para saber a localização do elemento entre elementos que partilham de uma mesma classe especifica? Por exemplo, quero que o index() ignore todas as outras classes exceto a classe `x`:

```
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
<div class="x index"></div>
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
```

No script:

```
console.log($(".index").index()); // resultado 3
```

No caso, quero que ele apenas conte como se existissem apenas elemetos com classe `x`

```
<!--<div class="y"></div> ignorado -->
<div class="x"></div>
<!--<div class="z"></div> ignorado -->
<div class="x index"></div>
<!--<div class="y"></div> ignorado -->
<div class="x"></div>
<!--<div class="z"></div> ignorado -->
```

No script:

```
console.log($(".index").index()); // resultado 1
```

Comment: Mas você já tem isso no exemplo que você fez, quando você faz $(".index"), você seleciona este elemento, agora é saber o que você quer fazer com esta seleção.

Comment: Você está querendo obter as outras classes do elemento? Explique melhor sua questão.

Comment: No caso o index() vai contar a localização usando todos os elementos, quero que ele conte apenas com os elementos de classe x, no exemplo acima ele vai apontar 3 (começa no 0), mas quero que ele aponte 1 pois vem um elemento dele antes com a classe 'x', invés de contar com todos os elementos, conte apenas com os elementos de classe x

Comment: Entendi o que você quer, mas qual o objetivo?

Comment: Estou criando um sistema de slide em um projeto de nuvem para o meu TCC, estou com o problema apenas nessa função para fazer a contagem da imagem atual que está sendo vista, tipo: "imagem 5 de 10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Resolução simples

Seleciono todos os elementos com a classe "x", faço um `foreach` até encontrar a classe "index" e então atribuo o 'index' para a variável "indice", retornando o valor que você deseja no caso "1",

```js
var indice = -1;
$('.x').each(function( index ) {
  if($(this).attr('class').includes('index'))
    indice =  index;
});
console.log(indice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
<div class="x index"></div>
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
```

## Solução utilizando o index

Caso exista a possibilidade do índice esta em y ou z, busco a classe "index" primeiro e a partir dela busco a letra que esta vinculada, pego e busco todos os itens desta letra, pego o index como no exemplo acima, só que de forma dinâmica usando a classe "index" para buscar a classe correspondente.

```js
var indice = -1;
$('.index').each(function( index ) {
  if($(this).attr('class').includes('index')){
    var classe = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $("."+classe).each(function( index ) {
      if($(this).attr('class').includes('index'))
        indice =  index;
    });
  }
});
console.log(indice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
<div class="x index"></div>
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

O método [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) no JQuery permite-lhe passar um seletor que refere os elementos em que você está interessado. Por isso no seu exemplo apenas tem de fazer assim:

```
$(".index").index(".x")
```

Que significa obter a posição do elemento com a classe `index` mas apenas considerando os elementos com a classe `x`.

Exemplo:

```js
console.log($(".index").index(".x"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
<div class="x index"></div>
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
```